# my first frame jig - a customized one - which addons and features to add?

Tags: frames, framebuilding

i am currently workin on the Bicycle-Frame-Building-Jig that is designed by tanner W at Instructables https://www.instructables.com/id/Bicycle-Frame-Building-Jig/

which bottom bracket assemblies should i work out:

The question is - which bottom bracket-assembly-types would you suggest!?which axles and dummy shells should i drill see https://www.instructables.com/id/Bicycle-Frame-Building-Jig/

well at the moment i am musing bout **the extras and features**

- what should i add
- which features should i add
- eg some dummy axles for the bottom bracket assembly - what do you suggest!?

i think as long as we can get a standard English bb in both 68 and 73,
we should be fine.

afaik: It's hard to deal with the press fit sizes because AFAIK nobody is selling facing/reaming tools for them. As far as i know: Paragon has a ton of bb shells available, so we could match what they sell.

but I think the two most standard sizes will probably do for now.

the tanner w fixture is adjustable for width, so we only need one set of blocks see here: https://www.instructables.com/id/Bicycle-Frame-Building-Jig/

and also see the bottom bracket shells: https://www.paragonmachineworks.com/frame-building-parts/bottom-bracket-shells/steel.html

well at the moment i am musing bout the extras - what should i add ?

Comment: Regarding press fit: Can’t you use a CNC milling machine to get the required precision?

Comment: i guess so.. I am mainly interested in english threaded shells - what do you tink aobut this!?! BTW - which dummy axles would you add - which things would you make better in this jig? love to hear from you

Comment: Backlink to dupe https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/72117/bike-frame-jig-customizations-of-a-standard-model-interesting-features-added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use tapered cones, so they work with any BB. There's no need to have different fittings for different BB.

Comment: hi there - many many thanks for this hint -  great!  BTW _ any thing that you would add to this jig !? Any thing that you would do aditionally!? Love to hear from you - regards

Comment: I'm not familiar with the jig in question. I made my own jig. But I have seen a few bicycle jigs and the tapered plugs for the BB and headtube are pretty typical because they work with different sizes.

Comment: thank you so much