# bike-frame-jig: customizations of a standard model - interesting features added

Tags: frames, innertube, aluminum

good day

i am in the mid of creating a bike-frame-jig.
the model is oriented at tanner w s jig: https://www.instructables.com/id/Bicycle-Frame-Building-Jig/

see some the parts (here as Acronyms ) he is using:
HT - Head Tube
ST - Seat Tube
TT - Top Tube
DT - Down Tube
BB - Bottom Bracket
CS - Chain Stay
SS - Seat Stay

note: i found two or three very interesting "hacks" of Tanner W: see the following pictures:

modifications made by Kristofer Henry

a. HT Assembly - The standoffs sit 45 deg.
https://www.flickr.com/photos/blackcapstudio/4913284984/in/gallery-186428325@N04-72157715964842548/

https://www.instructables.com/id/Bicycle-Frame-Building-Jig/

> So here is the HT Assembly pretty much put together with the exception
> of the bottom "puck" holder and purge fittings. The standoffs sit 45
> deg. back from the centerline of the extrusion. This allows me to have
> access to both sides of the HT/TT/DT area. I'll mount both standoff's
> on a rotary table and radius the ends to make my hands happy. Now that
> it is assembled, and I've had some time to stare at it long enough,
> I'm thinking I may change how the bottom standoff is mounted so it is
> fixed to the bottom of the extrusion and the whole assembly rotates
> off of it. Taking a measurement from the top of the main beam will
> enable an exact measurement to locate the bottom of the HT in space
> which will be nice..

and see the following discussion:

> Francois Cau: What did you use for the pivot point of the extrusion
> part ? Is it just a simple screw ? (I'm trying to find a good/precise
> solutions for Rev2.0 of my jig...)

Kristofer Henry:

> There is a shoulder bolt that rides on a pressed in bearing. It's
> pretty smooth and clamping action is good.

queston: - very very interesting .- Why did you change the standoff - with a 45 degree-skip?! Can you compare it with a standard - standoff

another hack: by kolb-Rahmenbau.ch
https://www.flickr.com/photos/186428325@N04/galleries/72157715964842548/with/3228571003/

he uses a very very big plate - see the right side  of the spine ...: the plate for the head tube assembly is very very big - much bigger than that one that Tanner W uses.
i guess that this is much more precicely .. he can work with a lower degree of measurement-failures

how do you see this !?
what do you think !?

What else do you like at this bike-frame-jig !? I think it is very very interesting - if we compare it with tanner ws jig!?

look forward to hear form you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [my first frame jig - a customized one - which addons and features to add?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/69659/my-first-frame-jig-a-customized-one-which-addons-and-features-to-add)

Comment: hi there - many thanks qjs - great to hear from you. Well at the moment i need some more help and insights into these above mentioned modifications - it would be a pleasure if you can help me here and share your thoughts.

Comment: I think a followup needed is how sophisticated are your machining fabrication skills / resources?